How To Automatically Copy and Paste Data from One Sheet to Another
Good morning. How do I automatically copy the data (with specific range) from one sheet to another in Google sheet? Here are the variables that I am using.
1st Step: In SheetA, it will copy all the data in cell B2:N6. I am using Cell A1 as a reference if what will be the Last Row.
2nd Step: It will paste the copied data to SheetB. I am also using Cell A3 as a reference in which cell it should start pasting the data. The copied data should be paste starting in Cell B12.
function CopyDataFromSheetAToB() {

  const sheetName = "SheetA";
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const row = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  const range = sheet.getRange("C2:N" + row);

  const sheetName2 = "SheetB";
  const sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName2);
  const row2 = sheet2.getRange("A3").getValue();
  const range2 = sheet2.getRange("B" + row2);

}



Can you please provide the link of your sample sheet and not just the image? This would allow community member to easily provide a targeted solution.
